# Laravel cant get the correct database name with DB::getDatabaseName()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an webapp with many companies and each one has one database, so I need to change the database constantly, I can do it easily on the auth provider, but I have some external links that don't need authentication

I do the dynamic connection with a class

```php
class DatabaseConnection {

    public static function setConnection($env_connection)
    {
        $env_connection = strtoupper($env_connection);

        config(['database.connections.mysql' => [
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => env("DB_{$env_connection}_HOST"),
            'database' => env("DB_{$env_connection}_DATABASE"),
            'username' => env("DB_{$env_connection}_USERNAME"),
            'password' => env("DB_{$env_connection}_PASSWORD"),
            'strict' => false,
        ]]);

        DB::reconnect('mysql');
    }
}
```

When I try to get the database name for some tests, it returns me `forge` the default one, that I didn't configure, it means that I shouldn't be possible to get the users, but I do, `DB::table('users')->count()` gets the correct connection but `DB::getDatabaseName()` don't

```php
DatabaseConnection::setConnection('different_database');
dump(DB::getDatabaseName()); \\ returns 'forge' instead of 'different_database'
dd(DB::table('users')->count()); \\ returns 3, thats the users from 'different_database' database
```

Am I doing something wrong or laravel is broken?

Comment: I think you may just define multiple databases connections in `database.php` like `mysql_company1`, `mysql_company2` and switch the connection with `DB::connection('mysql_company1')`

Comment: @loic.lopez But if I do it I'd need to return this connection to a variable and use that variable everywhere I needed to get something from the db

Answer (score 0):

use this

```php
try {
   $db_connection = DB::connection('different_database');
   dd($db_connection->getDatabaseName();
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
   dd($e);     
}
```

i just mimicked your issue now and this worked for me.
if it works, it will dump the DB name else catch and dump error

Comment: It would work, but I'd need to get this connection variable everywhere in my code, I'd like to just call DB::table or Model::

Comment: why dont you write a function for that instead?

Comment: That is a function, ` DatabaseConnection::setConnection` I do it once and I have that connection everywhere in my code, without using a variable, but the issue is with the method `getDatabaseName`

Comment: i think the previous connection somehow didnt close with the DB::reconnect('mysql'); because if it did close and new connection is set as default, the method getDatabaseName should work.

Comment: But if it happened also table('users')->count() would return the users from the previous connection and it don't

Comment: unfortunately, it works for me. i am using laravel 5.7 at the moment.

Comment: The same code worked for you? I'm using 5.5 it may be it, I should test

Comment: you should maybe check with 5.7

Comment: I expect not to work, cause my host provider don't support php 7.1